# Can gcloud be used to change the instance group a LB is pointing to?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

I'm trying to automate a process I'm currently doing manually.
I have an TCP load balancer, and I need to change the instance group it's directing the traffic to.
When doing it manually, it's pretty simple and straight forward, I just edit the LB setting in the web interface, and under "Backend configuration" switch between the instance groups:
[Manually changing via web interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBKb2.png)

I'm trying to replicate the process using gcloud, using the following command:

```
gcloud compute backend-services update-backend BACKEND-SERVICE-NAME --instance-group=INSTANCE-GROUP-NAME --instance-group-region=us-east4  --project=PROJECT
```

But get the following error:

```
(gcloud.compute.backend-services.update-backend) At least one property must be modified.
```

In the documentation of [gcloud compute backend-services update-backend](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/backend-services/update-backend?hl=en) it says:

> To add, remove, or swap backends, use the gcloud compute backend-services remove-backend and gcloud compute backend-services add-backend commands.

Does that mean it's not possible to replicate the process using gcloud?
I have first  to remove the instance group, and then add the new one, it will mean a partial traffic loss from LB.
How can I do the swap between backends without any downtime, as possible doing so via the web GUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**gcloud compute backend-services update-backend** updates attributes of a backend that is already associated with a backend service as per the GCP official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/backend-services/update-backend). It can not remove instance group or add new instance group to the LB backend service. To do that the following commands would help you to achieve this scenario but as you mentioned there will be a traffic loss from LB.

- To remove the instance group of a LB backend service.

```
 gcloud compute backend-services remove-backend BACKEND_SERVICE_NAME --instance-group=INSTANCE_GROUP   --instance-group-zone=INSTANCE_GROUP_ZONE --region=REGION --project=PROJECT
```

- To add a new instance group to the LB backend service.

```
 gcloud compute backend-services add-backend BACKEND_SERVICE_NAME --instance-group=INSTANCE_GROUP --instance-group-zone=INSTANCE_GROUP_ZONE --region=REGION --project=PROJECT
```

- To get the list of the available LB backend services.

```
 gcloud compute backend-services list.
```

To avoid down time you can use the rolling update feature in the GCE instance group. This [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/rolling-out-updates-to-managed-instance-groups) explains how to Automatically roll out updates to instances in a MIG.

Comment: I managed to change the backend-service instance group by exporting the configuration file with `gcloud compute backend-services export`, making the changes on the local file and then importing it with `gcloud compute backend-services import`
Does this have the same effect as swapping the instance group in the web interface, meaning no downtime?

Comment: @SimpleNiko I have tested the above scenario i could observe a few seconds down time, even if i change the instance group manually in LB i have observed few seconds down time as we are making changes in the LB it could take couple of seconds to come to the ready state as per my understating. I think in order to avoid down time you can use rolling update feature in the GCE instance group.